# add entity with many to many relation having proxy of related entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm curious, if it's possible to add entity and it's relation with other one, just by getting proxy by `getReference` method.

My entities looks as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
@NamedQuery(name="Book.findAll", query = "SELECT b from Book as b LEFT JOIN b.discountList as d where d.endingDate is null")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long bookId;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "ISBN")
    private String isbn;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    @Type(type="text")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "PUBLISHING_DATE")
    private Date publishingDate;

    @Column(name = "BASE_PRICE")
    private BigDecimal basePrice;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
            CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "BOOK_TO_DISCOUNT",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "discount_id")})
    private Set<Discount> discountList;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "DISCOUNT")
public class Discount {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long discountId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "RATE")
    private Integer rate;

    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    private Timestamp startingDate;

    @Column(name = "END_DATE")
    private Timestamp endingDate;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "discountList")
    private Set<Book> bookList;

}
```

My goal is to add a Discount which is related to some books, so I need to insert new promotion to the `DISCOUNT` table and add a relation into the `BOOK_TO_DISCOUNT` table.

Right now I'm doing this action in this way:

```
Set<Book> listOfLinkedBooks = discountData.getIdsOfBooksCoveredByThisDiscount().stream()
                .map(idOfBook -> entityManager.find(Book.class, idOfBook)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        Discount discount = new Discount(discountData.getDiscountId(),
                discountData.getName(),
                discountData.getRate(),
                discountData.getStartingDate(),
                discountData.getEndingDate(),
                listOfLinkedBooks);

        listOfLinkedBooks.forEach(a -> {
            Optional.ofNullable(a.getDiscountList()).orElseGet(Collections::emptySet)
                    .add(discount);
        });
        entityManager.merge(discount);
```

The disadvantage of this solution lays in usage of find method, because the hibernate fetches the all data of entity, when the entity is only needed to map relation connected with it. Looking from from DB point of view the id is enough to do so operation. Is there any chance to do it with usage of getRelation method?

The other solution, to optimize this operation, is to add new relation by hand, so I should create an entity for `BOOK_TO_DISCOUNT` table and just insert new relation manually. I perceive this idea as dirty one and implementation involves creating more entities. That is why I'm asking about usage getRelation in this case.

Comment: Why not fetch only the id's in a custom find method?

Comment: @K.Nicholas I already have id's of the books which should be related with persisted discount. The problem is that to add new relation I need to get previously inserted discounts to keep bidirection mapping consistent. I'm not sure, what u mean by custom find method, could u give me more details?

Comment: Right. Well you can insert relations directly into the `ManyToMany` table but you have to define the ManyToMany BOOK_TO_DISCOUNT table as an entity. Not terribly difficult and there are plenty of examples here how to do that. Then you can insert the id pairs directly.

Comment: @K.Nicholas I mentioned this solution in the last paragraph, but I'm curious if it's possible to do this by usage of the getReference method.

Comment: I see. I don't even know what "usage of getRelation" means so I can't comment. Assuming it is supposed to give you the BOOK_TO_DISCOUNT table then I suppose it's an interesting concept but I certainly can't comment on whether it's an acceptable solution or not. You didn't post the code you want to try and ask about that so instead of posting code that isn't about the question you're asking you might try it and post about the results of actual question.